# Como pegar uma palavra que esteja entre aspas antes de um determinado caracter

Tags: python, regex

Dada a seguinte string:

```
"series":"BB2222" OR "movies":"BBPS44"
```

O objetivo é pegar todas as correspondencias que antecedem o " : ", exemplo:

"series" e "movies"

tentei o seguinte regex:

```
(\"(.*?)+\")(?=:)
```

Porém ele pega literalmente tudo que antecede o ":" não importando se esta entre as aspas ou não.

A única forma que consegui foi a seguinte:

```
(\"[^\"]+\")(?=:)
```

vide: [exemplo](https://regex101.com/r/OODNxe/1)

Essa me retorna o objetivo apresentado, porém não consegui entender como. Teria forma melhor de faze-lo?

Comment: Um split no OR e nos resultados um split nos : não resolveria?

Comment: @AugustoVasques por se tratar de uma query lucene, a mesma pode ter outras condições e tamanho diferente, o objetivo é identificar os campos que estão vindo na query.

Comment: Olá Victor, como lhe [orientei antes](/q/575092/3635), se o and, or, etc são palavras chaves como separadores, nem precisa de [tag:regex], basta dividir a string baseado nessas palavras chaves, claro que existe a questão do escape em sintaxe lucene, o que vai exigir bem mais do que dividir ou que regex, na verdade em situações quem envolvem possíveis escapes penso que usar regex poderá ter dificuldades ou situações que serão impossíveis de resolver. Talvez seja melhor usar algo pronto, ex: https://lucene.apache.org/pylucene/index.html